# Traefik basic auth on path

Tags: traefik, traefik-authentication

I'm trying to password protect a specific path for an app, but it seems I am missing something and the traefik documentation is not helpful:

Paste from docker-compose:

### traefik:

```
command:
  - "--log.level=INFO"
  - "--providers.docker=true"
  - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
  - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
  - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
  - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
  - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge=true"
  - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
  - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=email@email.com"
  - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme.json"
```

### service:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.service.middlewares=service"
  - "traefik.http.routers.service.rule=Host(`domain.example.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.stsSeconds=31536000"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.stsIncludeSubdomains=true"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.stsPreload=true"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.referrerPolicy=no-referrer"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.browserXssFilter=true"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.service.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
```

If I add the following labels basic auth is working but it's enabled on the whole website:

- "traefik.http.middlewares.service-auth.basicauth.usersfile=/etc/traefik/auth"
- "traefik.http.routers.service.middlewares=service,service-auth"

I played around with adding a second router like so, but that doesn't seem to work:

- "traefik.http.routers.service-admin.rule=Host(`domain.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/somepath`)"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.service-auth.basicauth.usersfile=/etc/traefik/auth"
- "traefik.http.routers.service-admin.middlewares=service-auth"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to figure it out with some "educated" guesses. It seems the order of the labels and the spacing between them plays a vital role. Adding a second router (without a service) was indeed the correct way of accomplishing this but separating the routers and middlewares code blocks was important:

```
  - "traefik.enable=true"

  - "traefik.http.routers.service.rule=Host(`example.example.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.service-admin.rule=Host(`example.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/somepath`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.service.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
  - "traefik.http.routers.service-admin.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
  - "traefik.http.routers.service.middlewares=service"
  - "traefik.http.routers.service-admin.middlewares=service-admin"

  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.stsSeconds=31536000"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.stsIncludeSubdomains=true"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.stsPreload=true"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.referrerPolicy=no-referrer"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.browserXssFilter=true"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.service-admin.basicauth.usersfile=/etc/traefik/auth"
```

Note: traefik version used is 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are misconfiguring the second router, try to do it like this

```
"traefik.http.routers.service-admin.rule=Host(domain.example.com) && PathPrefix(/somepath)"
"traefik.http.middlewares.service-admin.basicauth.usersfile=/etc/traefik/auth"
"traefik.http.routers.service-admin.middlewares=service-admin"
"traefik.http.routers.service-admin.service=$yourservice"
```

Comment: From my understanding services are used mainly for layer 4/7 loadbalancing and they have to be specified in a separate dynamic config file. In any case specifying a service just returns a "the service \"servicename@docker\" does not exist" error and it seems to overcomplicate the setup in general.

Comment: You can specify the services either with labels or by `dynamic config file.`. if you do it with dynamic files, you need to reference it as service@${provider}. see this for more info https://medium.com/better-programming/traefik-2-1-as-a-reverse-proxy-c9e274da0a32

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and the solution seems to be related to the `priority` given for a route, see https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#priority.

The `routes` to consider are ordered by `priority` by traefik. The `priority` is, by default, determined by the length of the `rule` of the route. That is the reason why the accepted answer was working. The rule for the admin route is longer.

I would suggest to set a very high priority for such cases manually, because if you add more hosts or other expressions to your original non-admin route, traefik would basically ignore the admin route as it has a shorter `rule`.