# How to require a user to login in order to push to a docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, daemon, docker-registry

I am wondering how to set up my `docker-compose.yml` file or docker registry such that a user must login in order to push to the registry but any user can pull from the registry. Right now, no login is required to push to the registry. How can I require a login (username and password) when a user pushes?

Comment: How is the compose file setup now? What have you attempted?

Comment: Set the url of the docker registry in the image name. They must be authenticated to the registry.

Answer (score 1):

you can add authentication by configuring a "basic auth" on the reverse proxy.

if you use traefik you can do it by registering a middleware on the registry service's labels : traefik.http.routers.registry.middlewares=securityheaders,admin

and create this middleware : traefik.http.middlewares.admin.basicauth.users=admin:${HASHPASSWORD}

Then all requests to the registry will need a password. (full exemple below)

to apply basic auth only on some path you will need to follow this solution :
[Traefik basic auth on path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62367624/traefik-basic-auth-on-path)

or use another reverse proxy : nginx / haproxy / ...

```
    registry:
        restart: always
        container_name: registry
        image: registry:2
        volumes:
          - ./registry/data:/var/lib/registry
        environment:
          - REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
        labels:
            - traefik.enable=true
            - traefik.http.routers.registry.rule=Host(`registry.${DOMAIN}`)
            - traefik.http.services.registry.loadbalancer.server.port=5000
            - traefik.http.routers.registry.tls.certresolver=le
            - traefik.http.routers.registry.entrypoints=websecure

            # apply the admin middleware (created in traefik labels)
            - traefik.http.routers.registry.middlewares=admin

    traefik:
        image: traefik:latest
        container_name: traefik
        restart: always
        labels:
            ...
            # create a middleware named admin, to request a basic authentification of users
            # you can generate a user:password pair with this command :
            # echo $(htpasswd -nb user password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.admin.basicauth.users=admin:${HASHPASSWORD}"
            ...
```